# How would I do this in a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def every_second_line(report):
    """ (Open File for reading) -> list of str

    Return a list containing every second line (with leading and trailing
    whitespace removed) in report, starting with the first line.
    """
```

Comment: Have you tried solving that yourself?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: Try writing something you hope will work, then (if it doesn't), try asking why

Comment: I tried since last night... but okay for the future reference, I'll post my progress as well.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly, you would do it like this:

```
def every_second_line(report_location):
    """ This code will return every second line with trailing whitespace stripped."""
    report = open(report_location, rb+)
    second_lines = [a.strip() for a in report.readlines()[1::2]]

    return second_lines
```

I don't have Python with me at the moment, but this should work. Good luck!