# Read specific sequence of lines in Python

Tags: python, list, file, indexing, readlines

I have a sample file that looks like this:

```
    @XXXXXXXXX
    VXVXVXVXVX
    +
    ZZZZZZZZZZZ
    @AAAAAA
    YBYBYBYBYBYBYB
    ZZZZZZZZZZZZ
    ...
```

I wish to only read the lines that fall on the index 4i+2, where i starts at 0. So I should read the `VXVXV (4*0+2 = 2)...` line and the `YBYB...(4*1 +2 = 6)`line in the snippet above. I need to count the number of `'V's, 'X's,'Y's and 'B's` and store in a pre-existing dict.

```
fp = open(fileName, "r")
lines = fp.readlines()

for i in xrange(1, len(lines),4):
    for c in str(lines(i)):
        if c == 'V':
             some_dict['V'] +=1
```

Can someone explain how do I avoid going off index and only read in the lines at the 4*i+2 index of the lines list?

Comment: That's not correct, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just slice the list of lines?

```
lines = fp.readlines()
interesting_lines = lines[2::4]
```

Edit for others questioning how it works:

The "full" slice syntax is three parts: `start:end:step`

The `start` is the starting index, or 0 by default. Thus, for a 4 * i + 2, when i == 0, that is index #2.

The `end` is the ending index, or `len(sequence)` by default. Slices go up to *but not including* the last index.

The `step` is the increment between chosen items, 1 by default. Normally, a slice like `3:7` would return elements 3,4,5,6 (and **not** 7). But when you add a `step` parameter, you can do things like "step by 4".

Doing "step by 4" means `start+0, start+4, start+8, start+12, ...` which is what the OP wants, so long as the `start` parameter is chosen correctly.

Comment: In this case it is `lines[1::4]` but yeah, this works to grab the lines desired without using an index.

Comment: heh, that's much more sensible than my double-listcomp. +1

Comment: works like a charm! @Ittociwam could you please explain how this slicing translates to the logic?

Comment: I am confused as to how this slicing looks at each 4*i+2 index.  @Ittociwam

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say it avoids having to "go off of an index" of a for loop. Assuming that is what op means.

Comment: @AustinHastings lines[1::4] worked and I didn't try [2::4]. As per your reasoning, I am not sure why [1::4] works when it should be [2::4].

Comment: Remember that list/slice/array indexes start at 0, so line 0, line 1, line 2 would be the third line...

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the following:

Start `xrange` at 0 then add 2 onto `i` in secondary loop

```
for i in xrange(0, len(lines), 4):
    for c in str(lines(i+2))
        if c == 'V':
            some_dict['V'] += 1
```

Start `xrange` at 2, then access `i` the way specified in your original program

```
for i in xrange(2, len(lines), 4):
    for c in str(lines(i))
        if c == 'V':
            some_dict['V'] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear on what you're trying to do here--- are you actually just trying to only read the lines you want from disk?  (In which case you've gone wrong from the start, because `readlines()` reads the whole file.)  Or are you just trying to filter the list of lines to pick out the ones you want?

I'll assume the latter.  In which case, the easiest thing to do would be to just use a listcomp to filter the line by indices.  e.g. something simple like:

```
indices = [x[0] * 4 + 2 for x in enumerate(lines)]
filtered_lines = [lines[i] for i in indices if len(lines) > i]
```

and there you go, you've got just the lines you want, no index errors or anything silly like that.  Then you can separate out and simplify the rest of your code to do the counting, just operating on the filtered list.

(just slightly edited the first list comp to be a little more idiomatic)

Comment: Technically, I only need to read the lines at 4*i+2 but I just avoided going for that optimization for the sake of simplicity. I shall try this listcomp. Thanks!

Comment: note a couple of edits---the first listcomp is now more idiomatic, and the second has a bug removed.

Answer (score -2):

I already gave a similar answer to another question: [How would I do this in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35804704/how-would-i-do-this-in-a-file/35805205)

A better solution (avoiding unnecessary for loops) would be

```
fp = open(fileName, "r")
def addToDict(letter):
    someDict[letter] += 1;

[addToDict('V') for 'V' in str(a) for a in fp.readlines()[2::4]];
```

I tried to make this an anonymous function without success, if someone can do that it would be excellent.

Comment: Can you explain this : [2::4]?

Comment: Why use a list comprehension when you're not interested in the resulting list? Also, the function is completely unnecessary. `[somedict['V']+=1 ... ]` is much more pythonic. This doesn't avoid any for loops, you just can't see the for loop behind the list comprehension. Also, it seems like the OP is trying to increment the count of `'V'` every time it is matched, not once per line

Comment: Python will start reading the list from index 2, then every fourth element thereafter. It's known as slicing. The example that follows pertains to Numpy arrays, but it pertains just as well to regular lists: http://structure.usc.edu/numarray/node26.html

Comment: asdf: your suggested syntax throws an error for me in Python 2.7 (IDK if this has changed in Python 3). And yes, the for loop is hidden; there are no _explicit_ for loops in my suggestion; the list comprehension method is faster.

EDIT: You're right, I didn't read the original code properly, the OP wants to add 1 every time a 'V' is read. Updating my answer.

Comment: @Wer900 List comprehensions are faster in the case where the for loop is actually building a list ([See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22108640/2766650)). However, in this case a list is not being built, we're merely appending into a dictionary. Accumulating useless values slows the runtime significantly. A list comprehension is actually *slower* than the equivalent for loop in this case.